# How much should a person eat on Chol Hamoed, Shabbos and Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, food, yom-tov, meal-seudah, chol-hamoed

The Tanya said food eaten on Shabbos is automatically elevated. I hear from a chossid that people should not do hiskafia on shabbos. However, the local Rosh Yeshiva said that eating more is not a mitzvah on Shabbos, that a person should eat normally. I find that the amount of food eaten is always in inverse proportion to the amount of Torah and productive work I am able to accomplish.

There also appears to be injunctions to eat more on Chol Hamoed with the caveat that we shouldn't neglect the ruchnius either. Is there a mitzvah on Chol Hamoed to eat beyond the two seudahs per day? If so, how much? Is it as much as pleasurable?

Comment: related: [Do you have to eat bread meal(s) on every day of Chol HaMoed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70780/11501)

Comment: sorry my English is not that good. When you say "inverse proportion" do you mean to say that when you eat less you can learn more?

Comment: Yes and yes. It looks like you have to and I learn less if I eat more. Shabbat shalom

Answer (score 1):

The laws of eating meals on Shabbat are well-known and don't appear to be the core of your question, in any case [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (KSA) 77:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.77.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) provides a good overview.

The same KSA in [siman 103](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.103.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) provides a number of relevant rules regarding meals on Yom Tov. I picked a number of them but it is good to read the original.

> Just as it is a mitzvah to honor the Shabbos and delight in it, so it
> is a mitzvah to honor all the Yomim Tovim [...]
>
> What is meant by delight? [...] **on each Yom Tov day you must have two
> meals, one at night and one during the day**, but it is not our custom
> to have a third meal. [...] y**ou should be lavish with meat, wine and
> sweets**, according to your means.
>
> Every man is obligated to gladden the hearts of his wife, his
> children, and all who are dependent on him, in a way suitable for each
> [...] to the men, meat and wine. **It is the custom to serve a greater
> variety of foods on Yom Tov than on Shabbos**, because with regard to
> Yom Tov, the Torah mentions "rejoicing," but it is not mentioned with
> regard to Shabbos.
>
> Even though eating and drinking on festivals is a positive
> commandment, **you should not spend all day eating and drinking** [...]
>
> **And when you eat and drink, it is your duty to provide also for the
> orphan, the widow and other needy people** [...]
>
> When a person eats and drinks, and rejoices on the festival, **he should
> not overindulge in drinking wine**, in laughter and lightheadedness,
> thinking that the more he indulges, the greater will be the mitzvah of
> rejoicing.

KSA doesn't explicitly address meals on Chol Hamoed. R Aharon E. Marcus, in his excellent Halacha 24/7/12, writes (p. 264)

> According to most Poskim, **you should have a *reviit* or wine and a
> *kezayit* of meat every single day of Yom Tov, including Chol Hamoed**. R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach says that grape juice and poultry qualify as
> meat and wine, but R Moshe Feinstein and R Eliashiv say that you
> should consume alcoholic wine and beef.

Similarly R Dovid Zucker and R Moshe Francis in their [book on the laws of Chol Hamoed](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/CHOH.html) p. 21 write

> [...] each person should rejoice in the manner most compatible with
> his nature. Thus [on Chol Hamoed] according to many authorities, **a man should drink a *reviis* of wine daily** (some authorities allow grape juice instead of wine). It is also preferable to **eat a *kzayis* of
> meat daily** [and it is even permitted for women on their
> *mikve* day] (see there and appendix for sources)

See also [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-meals-of-chol-hamoed/) for the views of Shulchan Aruch HaRav.